# Url to download file from GCS bucket still accessible after deleting using Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

So I have problem when deleting file from GCS bucket, I create my file using java, the code is like:

```
public void upload(String projectId, String bucketName, String filePath, String fileName)
  throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

File f = new File(gcsCredDirectory+gcsCredFileName);
if (!f.exists()) {
  f.mkdirs();
}
try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f)) {
  StorageOptions storageOptions = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
      .setProjectId(projectId).setCredentials(fromStream(is)).build();
  Storage storage = storageOptions.getService();
  BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, fileName);
  BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
  Blob result = storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
  URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, MAX_EXPIRED_DATE, TimeUnit.DAYS, SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());
} catch (Exception e) {
  LOGGER.error("ERROR at GoogleCloudStorageServiceImpl.upload cause : ", e);
  throw e;
}
```

}

The code to create went well, I get the Url to download the file I uploaded and actually can download the file, but after I deleting the file through this code:

```
public boolean delete(String projectId, String bucketName, String fileName) {
    File f = new File(gcsCredDir+gcsCredFileName);
    if (!f.exists()) {
      f.mkdirs();
    }
    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f)) {
      StorageOptions storageOptions = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
          .setProjectId(projectId)
          .setCredentials(fromStream(is))
          .build();
      boolean result = storageOptions.getService().delete(bucketName, fileName);
      LOGGER.info("Object " + fileName + " was deleted from " + bucketName);
      return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I was able to see the log `Object + fileName + was deleted from + bucketName`, but when I access the Url to download the file, I can still download it. I expect the download should failed because the file was deleted.

Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has its own caches which will store what you upload for some time after you delete it. You need to override the settings using Headers on upload. Set `Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache`. You can also specify `public` or `private`.

- `public` means intermediate servers may cache the result (for faster response times).
- `private` means only the requesting client may cache the response, but not intermediate servers. This is usually set to enable a client to get a fresh copy each time the request is made.

To try and force the cache to drop the data, some servers accept `PURGE` requests. These can be issued via `curl -vv -X PURGE http(s)://example.com/path/to/resource`

Edit:

You can set the cache control headers using gsutil: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Will try it now :D , btw do you know how long the caches last? Thank you

Comment: I don't recall off the top of my head but its set as part of the meta data for the bucket object. I'll dig some stuff out if you really need the help but this information + search engine of choice should be enough to resolve any issue you're having with cached results.

Comment: Hi, I tried to dig the java library for setting cache control and no cache, didn't seem to find variable that seems fit, may I ask help how to set cache control and no cache through java? Thank you ...

Comment: Or it has to be set in the bucket itself?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata use gsutil